# Logic to identify a person uniquely

Tags: database, database-design, unique

I am working on a medical php application which will be implemented at national level.
It will be used by multiple hospitals and the patient record will be centralized i.e every hospital will be accessing and adding the patient records into same database.

I want that there should be only 1 record of a patient without any duplication. Simply speaking no hospital can again enter the 2nd record for same patient but in order to make it possible I need to know which criteria should we use which will remain fix throughout the entire lifetime of a patient. Only 2 are there in my mind i.e Name and Date of birth.

What other criterias can be there? I dont want to use mobile numbers and phone numbers etc. Moreover infants cant be having it. I need the criteria which will be there for every patient and unique.

Please give me your suggestions or any other better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: personal identification number , the number from your social security card or passport, also if you could validate these numbers with other existing datasources, that would be fine

Comment: This is the sort of question personally I'd ask the end-user, and sign off on it so if (probably when) it doesn't work 100% of the time you aren't held accountable.

Comment: @cristi_b - Its not for USA so there is no social security number for asian countries, also not everyone will be having passport. Lastly no datasource is available as well. We have to use the criteria which is available for every age group and sex like name and dob but we cant have unique patient with just the name and dob, so I need to know what else can be used

Comment: clients  should register and get a health card,  registration should undergo human validation process then, aldo birrh certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination of name, date of birth, blood group, place of birth etc., can be tried.

Comment: I cant use blood group as not every patients knows his / her blood group but yes place of birth can be a criteria but still wont gurantee a unique record for every patient, though I will add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot because I've been involved in some data matching and validation, although not specifically in the medical industry. You haven't specified a particular country, just mentioned Asia, so I'll use an example from my home country of Australia just because I'm familiar with the rules and I believe the same would apply to many Asian countries:

- We have a unique Medicare number used for health care, but it's not mandatory and while the free / discounted care means I expect 99%+ of people would have one you can't rely on it.
- There is also a tax file number, likewise not mandatory even if you
  work and people who have never had a job wouldn't normally have one.
- You might be dealing with foreign people that aren't residents.
- Drivers licenses are of course not mandatory to get healthcare.
- It's perfectly legal to have "no fixed address". Plus some people will lie to get treatments and repeats of drugs etc. Not to mention many people move often.
- Changing name is common in case of marriage / divorce and unless done
  for illegal purposes someone can change their name just because they
  don't like their original. Not to mention people use common substitutions for various things like Jim versus James.
- Typing mistakes will be very common over a large dataset.

In short I think the 'perfect' scheme you are asking for is impossible. The best you can do is apply a weighting rule to find likely duplicates. Same name / date of birth / place of birth for example is an unlikely but possible event so show a warning to the data entry operator it's a likely duplicate and let them see the details of the likely duplicate. Even things like a drivers license number that should be unique may indicate that the original entry just had a data entry error, not a new duplicate.

From my experience the best thing is a report that lists likely duplicates that must be reviewed by someone higher up the chain, and give them an easy option to merge the duplicates. Then you can start to use more vague regex expressions that throw a few false positives that can be dismissed when a human reviews them. You can also refine the model over time to get the best match results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some national-wide ID. Like Passport ID, or health insurance number.

Comment: not every patient like infants will be having it and I need the criteria which is available for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Social Insurance Number with country.

Comment: In my country there are duplicates, as birth certificate number is number of hospital + DOB.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing out I will edit for suggest something else